# Making a special sort of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, python-3.6

I have a python program in which I have a list which resembles the list below:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,2,7], [5,2,3], [7,8,5]]
```

Here I want to create a dictionary using the middle value of each sublist as keys which should look something like this:

```
b = {2:[[1,2,3], [4,2,7], [5,2,3]], 8: [[7,8,5]]}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,2,7], [5,2,3], [7,8,5]]

b = {}

for l in a:
  m = l[len(l) // 2]  # : get the middle element
  if m in b:
    b[m].append(l)
  else:
    b[m] = [l]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
{2: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 7], [5, 2, 3]], 8: [[7, 8, 5]]}
```

You could also use a `defaultdict` to avoid the `if` in the loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
b = defaultdict(list)

for l in a:
  m = l[len(l) // 2]
  b[m].append(l)

print(b)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 7], [5, 2, 3]], 8: [[7, 8, 5]]})
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Can we also do it by list comprehensions somehow??

Comment: It can sort of be done using dict comprehensions but it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [[1,2,3], [4,2,7], [5,2,3], [7,8,5]]

def get_mid(x):
    return x[len(x) // 2]

b = {key: list(val) for key, val in groupby(sorted(a, key=get_mid), get_mid)}

print(b)
```

Comment: `[I for I in value]` could be shortened a bit to just `list(value)`, and if you moved the lambda out to a separate function called `get_middle_value` then the code `groupby(a, middle_value)` would read beautifully.

Comment: Thanks, @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen. I cleaned it up a bit, but I am partial to the lambda for the sake of keeping it a one liner.

Comment: fair enough, [doc for `groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and after reading it reminds me that this might come into issues when elements with the same middle element aren't consecutive like `a = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,1,3]]` will omit the first element. This can be fixed with a call to `sorted` but should be using the same key function so it would make sense to move that out instead of duplicating it. ;)

Comment: Touché, I've patched it.